# SSIS Move a Table to other DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

In SSIS, I moved or transferred a table from one database to another. Here a short version, I selected a table from `ADO NET Source` and since my `ADO NET Destination` doesn't have the matching table, I did create it by clicking the button `New...` (this create a table right away). In Development environment it is fine, but when I move this to QA o Production it will fail since the table won't exist. 
Is there any property that will help me? for instance, a property called Create Table if it does't exists.
Or do you know a better design/code that improve this approach (read-write)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Data Flow Destinations object `SQL Server Destination`.

In the `SQL Destination Editor` click `New...` button by `Use a table or view:` and it will generate a SQL script to create the table before inserting.

[image]

Comment: But I think SQL Server Destination has a limitation, that it can connect to only local SQL Server database! so the best solution might be using Excute SQL Task.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `EXECUTE SQL TASK` and execute the following T-SQL statement inside your task.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Table_Name', 'U') IS NULL
  CREATE TABLE Table_Name
   (
   -- Columns here 
   );
GO
```